# DialogViewController Missing Back Button

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, xamarin, xamarin-studio, dialogviewcontroller

I am using the NavigationItem to drive the navigation of the application.  For all of my controllers inheriting from DialogViewController, the back button doesn't show, even if I do

```
BackButtonBarItem = news UIBarButtonItem(..)
```

The back button never shows only for dialogs, but does for every other type of controller.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the overloaded DialogViewController constructor

```
public DialogViewController (RootElement root, bool pushing)
```

the bool pushing parameter should be true if your DVC is being pushed onto a NavigationController.

Answer (score 2):

use

```
public YourDialog () : base (UITableViewStyle.Grouped, null, true)
```

instead of

```
public YourDialog () : base (UITableViewStyle.Grouped, null)
```